# special characters between php and java android using Json encode

Tags: php, android, json, utf-8, special-characters

As I site in the title I have accented characters encoding problem. 
I found several solutions on the web but it does not work or I do not know how to use. 
at the beginning: I collect all the data in php myssql base and I use the json_encode function returns the data to the application. This is where it crashes. all fields where there is a character with accents is replaced by null. 
data base is either a website (which I can not change it) and it is encoded in windows-1252 itself directly inserted with wampPHP 
why I found a solution

```
$liste_amis = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM lieux');



            $nombre_amis=0;
            while($myliste=$liste_amis->fetch()){


                foreach($myliste as &$value)
                    {
                     $value = mb_convert_encoding($value, "UTF-8", "Windows-1252");
                    }

                $output[]=array_map('utf8_encode', $myliste );




                 } 
print(json_encode($output));
```

but it works only for data inserted with wampPHP more it appears like this "discotA¨que" 
and in Logcat like this "discoth\u00c3\u00a8que"

and leftovers are always given the null

in my java code I use the BufferedReader

```
 try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8192);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            int i = 0;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                i++;
```

Help

**Edit :**

Finally it works, solution :

```
mysql_query ( "'utf8' SET NAMES" );
//--....... 
 while($myliste=$liste_amis->fetch()){
$output[]=array_map('utf8_encode', $myliste);
}
print(json_encode($output,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

java :

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
```

tanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your code to this...

```
foreach($myliste as &$value)
{
    $value = mb_convert_encoding($value, "UTF-8", "Windows-1252");
}
$output[]=array_map('utf8_encode', $myliste);
}
print(json_encode($output,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

Comment: @toufik3119, How you mean ?

Comment: tanks @Shankar  it works without converting .. I do not know why and how but it works .. tanks